# Is there a workaround to view Adobe Access (DRM) flash videos on any browser?

Tags: firefox, wine, google-chrome, flash, adobe

```
Ubuntu 13.04
Google Chrome   31.0.1650.57 (Official Build 235101) 
OS  Linux 
JavaScript  V8 3.21.18.7
Flash   11.9.900.152
```

When I try to watch xfinitytv shows via streaming (specifically homeland - showtime) I get stuck at the 0:00 and it says buffering...

Some problems:

- These streaming services now require flash versions 11.8 or higher.
- Adobe flash in browsers other than Chrome (ex. firefox) are only supported up to version 11.2. So this won't work.
- Google chromes uses Pepper flash which is supported up to 11.9!, but "Viewing Adobe Access (DRM) content is not supported, since Adobe does not support it on Linux." ([docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en))

So it looks like I am screwed. I need version 11.8 or higher which means firefox is out the door since adobe only supports it up to 11.2. Chrome's pepper flash is currently at version 11.9, but since it is a Adobe Access (DRM content) it is unsupported for linux users.

Any ideas? I have hit a wall. VM (WINE) the only option? Can I somehow get pepper flash into firefox?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `pipelight` which is a special browser plugin which allows one to use windows only plugins inside Linux browsers. It uses WINE the achieve this. It is usually used for silverlight, but it can be also used for flash. [Launchpad page of pipelight](https://launchpad.net/pipelight).

Please follow the [installation instructions](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_1_1) on the developer's webpage, and the [instructions for flash](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_2_3) on the same page.

Comment: Haven't had the time to try this yet, but I will get on it when I can. Thanks for the input!